# How can I avoid many request to my server (PHP-Java)?

Tags: java, php, android, security

I am developing an app for Android which allow users making comments. The problem is: if someone discovered the PHP file of my server which receive a comment and save it in a database this person would have a total control to save unlimited comments. So... How could I avoid this?

I don't know so much of security but... Could it be possible solve it with hash, keys or anything? How?

Comment: The best way is to implement the security features in the php fiels rather than the android app. You can check for captchas, check post content and how often someone posts :)

Comment: First: give privilieges of doing sth only to authenticated users Second: You can check cookies/ip and/or other and limit them  posts by time.

Comment: Thanks @Pphoenix "The best way is to implement the security features in the php" I know it, but I can't implement captchas for users because is an app of Android and It would be very annoying

Comment: You can use tokens.Generate a token for each user when he logs.Along with each request send this token.If the token matches with your db entry allow him to post a comment.

Comment: Ah, I see. I assume that adding some required fields (like the parameter SECURITY="test" must be set) wont make much of a difference. You could solve the problem by nonces :) You query the server for a value which can only be used one time, and then you can post one comment. That would increase security.

Comment: Thanks @AnR. How could I implement your first solution in Android?. About your second solution, couldn't an user change his IP easily and avoid this limit?

Comment: I like your solution @Tyranicangel, thanks. Do you know some websites to learn how could I implement tokens?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: This give some explanation about tokens etc. have a look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn270544(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Oauth and send a token with each request here a example link [Oauth2](http://ddewaele.github.io/AndroidOauth2GoogleApiJavaClient/) or you can use a more simple method like:

1. User log in you app then you create in a table a record with is id and random string
2. Return this string to the user
3. When user do request add this string
4. On PHP verify thata string exists and the id is correct then insert the comment else nothing

Comment: I am going to see your first solution, because in the second is the same case that now, someone could discover the php file which save the random string.